# Lightview3 - fixing the image position (The image is to low)

Tags: css, height, photo, image-gallery

I am using "[lightview](http://projects.nickstakenburg.com/lightview)" to show images in my website, the problem is that the image to much low, so I can see less than 50% of the photo

I that when I set Height to object in css, the image is lower

Here is my CSS code:

```
/****HTML Tags****/

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
    font-family: Arial, Arial Hebrew, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

::selection {
    background: #BFBFBF;
}


header {
    background-image: url('../g.png');
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #3852A4;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: x-large;
}


/****General****/

.content {
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.main {
    padding-right: 15px;
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(229,229,229,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(229,229,229,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e5e5e5', endColorstr='#00ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    background-size: Auto 200px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}

.details {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

    .details div {
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

#author {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#date {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/**Track Properties***/
#area {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.track {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 980px;
    width: 100%;
}

.trackdetails {
    position: relative;
    top: -51px;
    line-height: 25px;
    border-right: 2px solid #9e9e9e;
    padding-right: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    left: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
}

.title {
    color: #3852A4;
    font-size: large;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.trackdetails #content {
    z-index: 1111;
}

#map-image {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top:-50px;

}

#trackdescription {
    text-align: justify;
    max-width: 650px;
    width: 500px;
    float: right;
padding-bottom:100px;

}
```

How can I fix this?

Qish for help.. thanks!
***Here is live example:*** http://lawb.co.il/test.html

Answer (score 1):

Try `top: 10% !important;` or `margin-top: -n;` n = image box height / 2 :P n isn't a css property :)

Comment: Give me a link if you like, I can't imagine what's there, from the screen shot the top is massed up.

Comment: Sry, I was on lunch break. Eather you fixed it or it was just a cache problem, for me it works just fine, the box is centered. I tested on firefox, chrome, opera, ie9 and no problem was found :)

Comment: Thank you, but if you notice, you can't see the navigators at the bottom of the photo, and this is the ain problem - that if I set paddingqmargin/height than the photo is lower than the regular..

Comment: I got my solution Thsanks!